# How do I implement RRT or RRT* algrithm with ROS?

Tags: ros, kinect, global-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to implement other path planning algrithm for ROS robot navigation,but I don't how to do it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339539/how-do-i-implement-rrt-or-rrt*-algrithm-with-ros?/) by [hubery524](https://answers.ros.org/users/46310/hubery524/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2019-12-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please have a look at this answer:
https://answers.ros.org/question/339540/how-do-i-implement-other-path-planing-algrithm-for-ros-global_planner/?answer=339542#post-id-339542

---

Originally posted by [kurshakuz](https://answers.ros.org/users/42874/kurshakuz/) with karma: 76 on 2019-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0